# How to make a folder with name as date_time and copy a specified .bat file into that

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to make a folder with name as date_time and copy a  specified .bat file into that.
I want to use .bat file for above stated functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try using search because working datestamps and DOS have been around for many years.

Try this:

```
set "newdirectory=c:\%date:/=-%-%time::=-%"
md "%newdirectory%"
```

will create something like "Thu 01-15-2015-14-41-19.61" (depending on your local date/time settings)

Had to look up substring replace and found this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/6159108/4317867

-Edit, add explanations.

MD using the system variables `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` but replace the invalid characters `/` and `:`

Comment: There are already %date% and %time% system variables that can be used. Also, the `str=` part is going to break absolutely everything.

Comment: @user4317867: `set %date% = date /t` ?? Did you try that?

Comment: @Stephan I'm not the author of the question and I didn't know about those system variables.  I also removed str = in my test batch file and things still work.

Comment: yes, your `md`line works; because it uses the systemvariables `%date%` and `time%`. Not because, but in spite of the two `set`commands. `set %date% = date /t` is as wrong as it could be made. It sets a variable `15.01.2015<space>` to the string `<space>date /t`

Comment: Well that is helpful to me but not so much to the question author.

Essentially the command in a batch file can be simply `md "c:\%date:/=-%-%time::=-%"`

Comment: OP will need to use the directory created later in the batch, so you need to set a variable in case the time has changed when the time comes to use the directory hence pulling the same date-time method won't be valid. Quoting in the manner shown ensures trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned.